# NullPointerException on Restful Web Service from Database

Tags: rest, netbeans, nullpointerexception, entitymanager

I am very new on restful web service development. I tried to create one from database (local mysql) using Netbeans' template. I have a table called "workplaces" in db. 
This is my WorkplacesFacadeREST.java:

```
@Stateless
@Path("com.rest.api.workplaces")
public class WorkplacesFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Workplaces> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "com.rest_hiring_challenge_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
    private EntityManager em;
public WorkplacesFacadeREST() {
    super(Workplaces.class);
}

@POST
@Override
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void create(Workplaces entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}

@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void edit(@PathParam("id") Integer id, Workplaces entity) {
    super.edit(entity);
}

@DELETE
@Path("{id}")
public void remove(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    super.remove(super.find(id));
}

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public Workplaces find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    return super.find(id);
}

@GET
@Override
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<Workplaces> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}

@GET
@Path("{from}/{to}")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<Workplaces> findRange(@PathParam("from") Integer from, @PathParam("to") Integer to) {
    return super.findRange(new int[]{from, to});
}

@GET
@Path("count")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String countREST() {
    return String.valueOf(super.count());
}

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

}
```

AbstractFacade.java:

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }

}
```

My entity class Workplaces.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "workplaces")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Workplaces.findAll", query = "SELECT w FROM Workplaces w"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Workplaces.findBySpId", query = "SELECT w FROM Workplaces w WHERE w.spId = :spId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Workplaces.findByWorkers", query = "SELECT w FROM Workplaces w WHERE w.workers = :workers"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Workplaces.findByLatitude", query = "SELECT w FROM Workplaces w WHERE w.latitude = :latitude"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Workplaces.findByLongitude", query = "SELECT w FROM Workplaces w WHERE w.longitude = :longitude")})
public class Workplaces implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "sp_id")
    private Integer spId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "workers")
    private int workers;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "latitude")
    private float latitude;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "longitude")
    private float longitude;

    public Workplaces() {
    }

    public Workplaces(Integer spId) {
        this.spId = spId;
    }

    public Workplaces(Integer spId, int workers, float latitude, float longitude) {
        this.spId = spId;
        this.workers = workers;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public Integer getSpId() {
        return spId;
    }

    public void setSpId(Integer spId) {
        this.spId = spId;
    }

    public int getWorkers() {
        return workers;
    }

    public void setWorkers(int workers) {
        this.workers = workers;
    }

    public float getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(float latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public float getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(float longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (spId != null ? spId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Workplaces)) {
            return false;
        }
        Workplaces other = (Workplaces) object;
        if ((this.spId == null && other.spId != null) || (this.spId != null && !this.spId.equals(other.spId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.rest.api.Workplaces[ spId=" + spId + " ]";
    }

}
```

So when I tried to access `http://localhost:8080/hiring_challenge/com.rest.api.workplaces/count`. It gives me HTTP 500 error tomcat page. Here is the exception details:

```
exception

org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:365)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:233)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:557)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.rest.api.service.AbstractFacade.count(AbstractFacade.java:47)
    com.rest.api.service.WorkplacesFacadeREST.countREST(WorkplacesFacadeREST.java:80)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

I tried debugging it. It turns out my `EntityManager em` is null at run time. I checked `PersistenceContext`'s unit name for my `EntityManager em`. It's same as specified as in my `persistence.xml`. I used Netbeans "Create RESTful Web Service from Database" to create these files from my local mysql db. Can someone give me some help please?

**UPDATE:**
I solved the problem by adding:

```
em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.rest_hiring_challenge_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU").createEntityManager();
```

into my WorkplacesFacadeREST.java's `getEntityManager()` method. However, I am getting a page without any xml back though. So this is the new problem...Help?

**UPDATE:**
I was missing mySQL jdbc driver. After added that, the project worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mySQL jdbc driver was missing.